# is setTimeout is part of javascript window object?

Tags: javascript, window, settimeout

Is `setTimeout()`, a part of an ajax call (`XMLHttpRequest`), `console`, `localStorage` or a `window` object ?

Comment: `["setTimeout","XMLHttpRequest","console","localStorage" ].map(hasOwnProperty, window)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each window (even iframe) has these APIs.

All global functions are methods of the [window](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp) object

You can test it for yourself by running these commands from your browser's console

```
window.setTimeout 
window.XMLHttpRequest 
window.console
window.localStorage
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification